# Scheme: Finding Divisors

Tags: scheme

I am working on writing a function that counts the number of divisors a number has. For example 4 would have 3 divisors. I wrote a helper function as follows:

```
(define (divisors-upto n k)
  (cond((= k 0) 0)
      ((= n 0) 0)
      ((= k 1) 1)
      ((divides k n) (+ 1 (divisors-upto n (- k 1))))
      (else (divisors-upto n (- k 1)))))
```

but in my next function I am having trouble utilizing my helper function properly. Will the following function work for counting divisors?

```
(define ( divisors n ) ( divisors-upto n n ))
```

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: As an optimization, change ((divides k n) (+ 1 (divisors-upto n (- k 1)))) to ((divides k n) (+ 2 (divisors-upto n (- k 1)))) and the call to (define (divisors n) (let ((root (sqrt n)) (if (integer? root) (+ 1 (divisors-upto n root)) (divisors-upto n (floor root))))

Comment: And minorly ((= n 0) 0) case into divisors so you only have to check for it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure looks good *in principle*. As long as the procedure `divides` is correctly implemented, it should work without problems. For example:

```
(divisors 10)
=> 4 ; 10, 5, 2 and 1 are divisors of 10
```

FYI, when you have a helper procedure that gets called with one or more extra parameters from the "main" procedure, *and* the helper procedure is never going to be used elsewhere, it's a good idea to declare the helper as an inner definition, for example:

```
(define (divisors n)
  (define (divisors-upto n k)
    (cond ((= k 0) 0)
          ((= n 0) 0)
          ((= k 1) 1)
          ((divides k n) (+ 1 (divisors-upto n (- k 1))))
          (else (divisors-upto n (- k 1)))))
  (divisors-upto n n))
```